# LAMP server php files show the code instead of running it

Tags: php, apache2, lamp

I had a lamp server installed and the server stopped working. I have fixed that problem and the server works now, however when running a php file it just displays the code instead of runnning it. I think this problem may have to do with the fact that i have reinstalled apache2 to try to get my server to work. Im guessing it had messed up some the configuration between apache and php however i have no idea how to fix it.

I also have mysql installed which i cannot test on the server until php is working again.

Comment: also my operating system is ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but did you add the .php extension in your httpd.conf file?

Comment: I dont remember having to add anything the first time (and I also copied and pasted the apache2.conf file which i believe you are referring to) but I am up to suggestions. what would i need to do?

Comment: it also might be useful to know that i am running my server on a desktop version of ubuntu and used `tasksel` to install the components originally.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have not configured apache to use php, this is from my conf file

```
#PHP Include
Include conf/extra/php5_module.conf
```

and

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

apache service would require a restart after any edits

Comment: adding those lines created an error since the files dont exist in those spots on my computer. i noticed in the conf-available there is a file called php5-cgi.conf which is the only file not linked to in the conf-enabled folder. is this the problem? I tried including that file and it didnt cause an error but it didnt fix it or add the link into the conf-enabled folder.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type might be set to `text/plain`. Change it to `text/html` instead.

Comment: im positive it is not the website itself because i have many many pages that all worked before reinstalling apache and now wont work after without any changes to the websites themselves. Also i have downloaded a free php blog site to use and that doesnt work either, along with phpmyadmin